# Linux support for Intel GMA 3650

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics

I recently purchased an Intel D2700DC motherboard and I quickly realised there are no Linux drivers for the integrated graphics (Intel GMA 3650).

Does anyone know if there will be any driver in the foreseeable future? Or should I return it and look for another motherboard?

Comment: There is already an [ongoing discussion on the Ubuntu community](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953734&highlight=intel+gma+3650&page=3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get Ubuntu working for the Intel D2700DC motherboard. Unfortunatly the only thing that works right now is HDMI output and correct resolution. This means only 2D support and no HW accelaration. HD/DVD/Bluray videos are not viewable.

If you still want to try it out, follow these steps:

> 1. take the 3.4-RC7 tree branch, unzip
> 2. copy the current contents of the gma500/ folder from the linux next-branch over 3.4-RC7 files
> 3. re-compile the kernel as 3.4-RC7 (well, with a slightly modified gma500 driver
>
> Give it some time to load because the specific kernel booted me
>   directly into xorg instead of console. Also, I have disabled LVDS by
>   appending this to existing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX entries: video=LVDS-1:d

I snatched these steps [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1953734&highlight=intel%20gma%203650&page=10) from the user **axw**

Answer (score 1):

See: "Intel PowerVR GMA 3600/3650 linux driver released!" at https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144445